# Wifi keeps disconnecting randomly on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless, lenovo

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on Lenovo Y50-70 in a dual boot setup allong with Windows 8.1. 3-4 times a day, the Wifi wold just disconnect suddenly and then automatically reconnect within a minute or two. Sometimes, it would fail to find any available connections and then I have to turn of the Wifi for 2-3 minutes and then it would reconnect. I have been facing these issues for atleast the past 4 months. Before that I was only using Windows and something like this would only happen about once or twice a month.

Here's the output of `sudo lshw -class network`:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: wlp8s0
       version: 01
       serial: 30:10:b3:a2:42:d7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.15.0-147-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.100 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:17 memory:d1600000-d167ffff memory:d1680000-d168ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: enp9s0
       version: 10
       serial: f0:76:1c:0b:b0:19
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:18 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:d1504000-d1504fff memory:d1500000-d1503fff
```

EDIT: Output of `iwlist freq`:

```
lo        no frequency information.

enp9s0    no frequency information.

wlp8s0    13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
```

Output of `sudo iwlist scan`:

```
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp9s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlp8s0    Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 98:DA:C4:3B:F4:6E
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=36/70  Signal level=-74 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"MY-WIFINAME"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000045b351da7e
                    Extra: Last beacon: 216ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000667617574616D
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B961224486C
                    IE: Unknown: 03010B
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C183060
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A6E1017FFFF000001000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D160B070600000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 7F09000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 0B05040000127A
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: 4A0E14000A002C01C800140005001900
                    IE: Unknown: DD8D0050F204104A0001101044000102103B0001031047001038833092309218839C7798DAC43BF4C41021000754502D4C696E6B10230009544C2D57523834304E10240003362E3010420003312E301054000800060050F20400011011001B576972656C657373204E20526F7574657220544C2D57523834304E10080002210C103C0001011049000600372A000120
                    IE: Unknown: DD07000C4300000000
```

Router page images:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: That it happened as well in Windows, albeit infrequently, suggests a problem with the router's settings.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `iwlist freq` and `sudo iwlist scan`. Tell me which networks you connect to. In the router, what channels are the 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz networks set to? WPA2/AES on both the computer and the router? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them. ps: did you clean out the dust yet? This could be a factor for this problem also.

Comment: Install `linssid` and check for neighborhood network congestion around the channels that you're using. We may have to adjust the settings in the router. Are you in a home or apartment?

Comment: If/when you open the computer to clean it, also re-seat the modem card in its slot. Be careful not to dislodge the antenna wires, as they're a pain to get reconnected.

Comment: In the router, is "20/40 co-existence" enabled? You'll find that setting in the wireless setup tab/page.

Comment: @heynnema Yes I had cleaned the dust on Tuesday, however, I did not re-seat the modem, I will try to do it tomorrow. I have added the ouputs of those commands. Yes, WPA2/AES on both the router and the laptop. Ran `linssid` scan for an hour and it only detetced my wifi, but ocassionally I can see the neighbours Wifi connection, however not this time on `linssid`. I live in a home, but the neighbouring houses are very close and definitely within Wifis range, so interference MIGHT be an issue.

Comment: @heynnema I did not find anything related to "20/40 coexistance" but I have posted images of some pages which I felt might be relevant.

Comment: With "Signal level=-74 dBm" I'd expect wireless connectivity problems. Is the router centrally located in the house, and high up (not on the floor)?

Comment: @heynnema The router is placed on a small table at a height of about 2ft (24 inches). Distance wise its more than 25 feet away from where I use my laptop. I took my laptop closer to the router and even then the signal quality and levels ONLY improved to 55/70 and -55 dBm respectively. Should I just place the router at a higher place and closer to where I use my laptop?

Comment: Try higher first. Closer to the router and still only -55dBm signal? It should be higher. Maybe your router needs replace. That might also be why "all" the networks disappear from your computer (as you only have one network in range). The router is kind of old.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @heynnema Sorry for the delay, I simply changed the routers location 2 days ago and it has been working good so far. Signal strength mostly stays in the range -50 to -60dBm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments...

The existing router has a weak signal, and is positioned 2 feet off of the floor.

After changing the router's location, it's been working well.

Further problems may require replacing the old router.